# using "final" keyword in java

Tags: java, final

I have came across the `final` keyword, which apparently locks in a value so it cannot be changed later. But when I try using it, the variable `x` still is changed. Am I going wrong somewhere?

```
public class Class {
  // instance variable
  private int x;

  public Class() {
    // initialise instance variables
    final int x = 123;
  }

  public void sampleMethod() {
    // trying to change it using final again
    final int x = 257;
    System.out.println(x);

  }
  public void sampleMethod2() {
    // trying to change it using without using final
    x = 999;
    System.out.println(x);
  }

}
```

Comment: because you are setting the local variable `x` in the method `sampleMethod` and your constructor to be final, not the class variable `x`.

Comment: You must make the variable final for the whole class, not just constructor/method, because variables declared in methods are local. When the constructor finishes for example, the final int x = 123 gets out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Class {
  // instance variable  
  private int x; // <-- This variable is NOT final.

  public Class() {
    // initialise instance variables
    final int x = 123; // <-- This is NOT the instance variable x, but rather hiding this.x with a method local variable called 'x'
  }

  public void sampleMethod() {
    // trying to change it using final again
    final int x = 257; // <-- This is NOT the instance variable x, but rather hiding this.x with a method local variable called 'x'
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(this.x); // see!

  }
  public void sampleMethod2() {
    // trying to change it using without using final
    x = 999; // This changes this.x, but this.x IS NOT final.
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

Now lets see how we actually create a final variable:

```
public class ClassWithFinalInstanceVariable {
    private final int x;
    public ClassWithFinalInstanceVariable() {
       this.x = 100; // We can set it here as it has not yet been set.
    }
    public void doesNotCompileIfUncommented() {
       // this.x = 1;
       // If the line above is uncommented then the application would no longer compile.
    }

    public void hidesXWithLocalX() {
       int x = 1;
       System.out.println(x);
       System.out.println(this.x);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You chould change your code to:

```
public class Class {

    private final int x;

    public Class() {
       x = 123;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring thrice you should declare it once.
Infact `sampleMethod2()` is not required

```
public class Class {
  // instance variable
  private final  int x;

  public Class() {
    // initialise instance variables
    x = 123;
  }

  public void sampleMethod() {
    // You will get error here
    x = 257;
    System.out.println(x);

  }

}
```

Comment: sampleMethod will not compile, as well as sampleMethod2

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak OP Wanted to know why its not giving compilation error. So I removed that declaration so that it throws that error which OP expected. Before downvoting read the question first

Comment: Please add a comment, saying where to expect compilation errors

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak  Added